# Xcodebuild with App thinning in Xcode 10 generates 2 ipas

Tags: ios, swift, xcodebuild, xcode10, app-thinning

I have a question regarding app thinning and Xcode 10.

When I try to do `xcodebuild` for my application with `exportOptionsPlist`, thinning set to `iPod7,1`, it generates 2 ipas one with `[OS 10]` and other with `[OS 12]`

```
[device: iPhone6,2, os-version: 12]..
[device: iPhone6,2, os-version: 10]..
```

If I do the same with a archive created with Xcode 9, it only generates one ipa with `[OS 10]`

```
[device: iPhone6,2, os-version: 10]..
```

Can some one please give me some insight in to this. Is this because of 32/64 bit architectures or is it something else?

Comment: You have a solution already?

I have the same issue. And I can't install ipa generated from Xcode 10. My temp solution is not using App thinning for Xcode 10.

Comment: Not really, we did the same. So the both ipas you could not install ?

Comment: I tried both ipa, neither can be installed. So that I stop using app thinning. But the app size increase almost 2 times.